# Showing error Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, android

When I press the button(named "current location") it should shows current location(lat & long) on the textview(named "tvAddress") .But it's not working as I expect. It's giving me errors.Errors are given below.Can anyone help me plz

**Error is :**

```
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3680)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3675)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    ... 11 more
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    at com.mamun.tasktest.MapActivity.marker(MapActivity.java:129)
02-05 23:37:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20293):    ... 14 more
```

**MapActivity.java**

```
package com.mamun.tasktest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapActivity extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private LocationManager manager;
    private TextView tvAddress;
    private Button btncurrent;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        tvAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvaddress);
        btncurrent= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncurrent
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    }

    public void marker(View v) {

        Location currentLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();
        tvAddress.setText(currentLocation.getLatitude()+" , "+ currentLocation.getLongitude());
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            ArrayList<Address> addresses = (ArrayList<Address>) geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), 5);
            Address addr = addresses.get(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        locationClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        locationClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search your location" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvaddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btncurrent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="marker"
            android:text="Current Location"
              android:layout_marginLeft="98dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnsave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
         <fragment
            android:id="@+id/maps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `findViewById` before setting the View, so when you call `tvAddress.setText`, `tvAddress` is null. Start with this code instead :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    tvAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvaddress);
    btncurrent= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncurrent);

    locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);


}
```

Also, you got the error wrong, the real cause is this :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mamun.tasktest.MapActivity.marker(MapActivity.java:129)
```

Take your time to read the stack trace carefully and look for places where it points to classes you wrote, it is always a good place to start for investigating bugs ;)

Comment: Finally, as a bonus, it is a good practice to check for availability of Google Play Services, more info here : http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Answer (score 2):

Your first two lines in onCreate method should be these ones:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.map);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I update the **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1**

The solution that works for me is to change the Gradle JDK to Embedded JDK version 11.0.15

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just you have wrongly initialized your views. As you can only access the views after `setContentView()` method and you have done that totally reverse that is why its throwing error.

Just change your `onCreate()` as below:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.map);
   manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    tvAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvaddress);
    btncurrent= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncurrent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not related to this question but this error also comes due to data binding errors.

```
1. Check if your variable is pointing to the correct data class
2. Check if your fields due for your views (text view, visibility are correct)
3. You have imported the correct imports (for eg for visibility related operations)
```