# .setBackgroundResource crashing my app

Tags: java, android

In the app, whenever i try to check the grey option and click my button, my app crashes.All the other radio buttons work perfectly fine but whenever i try to change the background color of my layout through the grey button, the app crashes.
P.S when i removed `instructionlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);` from the code, grey also worked just fine and toasted "Grey". Please help me on how to change my background color on all of my layouts without the app crashing.

```
public void setter(View setv)
{
    RelativeLayout instructionlayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.instructionslayout);
    switch(setv.getId())
    {
        case R.id.changecolorbtn:
            int id = SelectedRadioButton();
            switch(id)
            {
                case 1:toost("Original");break;
                case 2:toost("Grey");instructionlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);break;//problem is here
                case 3:toost("Red");break;
                case 4:toost("Orange");break;
                case 5:toost("Yellow");break;
                case 6:toost("Green");break;
                case 7:toost("Aqua");break;
                case 8:toost("Marine");break;
                case 9:toost("Purple");break;
                case 10:toost("Silver");break;
                default:toost("Error! - Select An Option!");
            }
            break;
    }
}
public int SelectedRadioButton()
{
    RadioButton original = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.origcolor);
    RadioButton grey = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.grey);
    RadioButton red = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.red);
    RadioButton orange = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.orange);
    RadioButton yellow = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.yellow);
    RadioButton green = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.green);
    RadioButton aqua = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.aqua);
    RadioButton marine = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.marine);
    RadioButton purple = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.purple);
    RadioButton silver = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.silver);
    int starter = 1;
    switch(starter)//take advantage of switch falling without break statement
    {
        case 1:if(original.isChecked()){return 1;}
        case 2:if(grey.isChecked()){return 2;}
        case 3:if(red.isChecked()){return 3;}
        case 4:if(orange.isChecked()){return 4;}
        case 5:if(yellow.isChecked()){return 5;}
        case 6:if(green.isChecked()){return 6;}
        case 7:if(aqua.isChecked()){return 7;}
        case 8:if(marine.isChecked()){return 8;}
        case 9:if(purple.isChecked()){return 9;}
        case 10:if(silver.isChecked()){return 10;}
    }
    return -1;//if nothing is checked
}
```

colors.xml:

```
<resources>
<color name="original">#25383C</color>
<color name="grey">#484849</color>
<color name="red">#881A27</color>
<color name="orange">#ffa500</color>
<color name="yellow">#CDE707</color>
<color name="green">#00ff00</color>
<color name="aqua">#00FFCC</color>
<color name="marine">#0C0C84</color>
<color name="purple">#630A86</color>
<color name="silver">#c0c0c0</color>
</resources>
```

logcat:

```
10-22 10:32:49.834  17834-17834/dhruvyadav.msplit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: dhruvyadav.msplit, PID: 17834
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3983)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3978)
```

I have tried:

```
 View instructionlayout = (View)findViewById(R.id.instructionslayout);
 instructionlayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.grey);
```

How do i put a ui thread between my .setBackground code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598165/showing-error-caused-by-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception

Comment: Properly check if your instructionlayout view is properly bind using `findViewById`. Debug it line by line and check that instructionlayout is not null. What I am thinking is you're not using right Id. Otherwise, in activity your code should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

you using setBackgroundColor

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.your_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
instructionlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

instead of:

```
instructionlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.original);
instructionlayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

or

```
instructionlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.original);
```

Comment: `setBackgroundResource` method can also use Drawable, Bitmap, Color.

Comment: is there `setter` method in `activity`? UI works is possible only on activity main thread.

Comment: setter method is in Settings.java which is for my setting layout activity.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below code.. It works for me.. I  hope it will help you...

Use this

instructionlayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

Instead of

instructionlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);